# zerorpc python hello world client on Mac not working

Tags: python-2.7, zeromq

i try to use zerorpc python client like this:

```
import zerorpc

c = zerorpc.Client()
c.connect("tcp://127.0.0.1:4242")
print c.hello("RPC")
```

and i get this error at start

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Programming/python/snmp01/snmp01.py", line 34, in <module>
    print c.hello("RPC")
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/zerorpc-0.4.3-py2.7.egg/zerorpc/core.py", line 256, in <lambda>
    return lambda *args, **kargs: self(method, *args, **kargs)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/zerorpc-0.4.3-py2.7.egg/zerorpc/core.py", line 241, in __call__
    return self._process_response(request_event, bufchan, timeout)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/zerorpc-0.4.3-py2.7.egg/zerorpc/core.py", line 225, in _process_response
    raise
zerorpc.exceptions.RemoteError: Error: Hello, RPC
    at Server._recv.result (//Programming/node/snmp01/node_modules/zerorpc/lib/server.js:146:55)
```

any idea?

Comment: Can you share the code of the nodejs server so we can reproduce the problem?

Answer (score 6):

The [docs](http://zerorpc.dotcloud.com) are currently wrong.  If there is no error on the node side, you need to pass `null` as the first argument to `reply`.  The first argument is for errors (as it says further down in the docs.)

My CoffeeScript code that works looks like this:

```
zrpc = require 'zerorpc'
server = new zrpc.Server
  hello: (name, reply) ->
    reply null, "Hello, #{name}!"
server.bind 'tcp://0.0.0.0:4242'
```

Comment: Have you got a working example for the reverse case? (python server and node.js client)

Comment: UGH. ridiculous that the official source has been catastrophically wrong for 2 years.